# Having problem finding the maximum value of a row of values in R

Tags: r

I wrote the following code to read an excel data sheet (Data1) and find the maximum value of all the rows.

```
library(readxl)
df <- read_xlsx("Data 1.xlsx", col_types = "text", col_names = TRUE) 

df 


   Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4    Q5    Q6    Q7    Q8    Q9    Q10   Q11   Q12   Q13   Q14   Q15  
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
  3     6     5     5     9     7     3     11    4     2     5     6     6     15    3    
  0     1     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     2     2    
  3     4     2     1     5     4     5     3     3     3     4     7     3     11    4 

df$max<-apply(df, 1, max) 

df$max
[1] "9"   "2"   "7"
```

So, this is clearly not right as the maximum value of the first row is 11 and it is showing 9.
Anyone has any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: You almost certainly have a character column.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
tapply(as.numeric(unlist(df)), row(df), max)

 1  2  3 
15  2 11 

matrixStats::rowMaxs(as.matrix(type.convert(df, as.is =TRUE)))
[1] 15  2 11
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `pmax` with `do.call` in `base R`

```
do.call(pmax, type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE))
[1] 15  2 11
```